# getting rid of characters in an output in python

Tags: python

If someone writes 'james', I want my program to style their name as j*a*m*e*s
I thought it would be simple:

```
for letter in name:
 print letter+' *',
```

but I don't know how to get rid of the last asterix at the end.

I had a friend show me in C though...so I understand the underlying concept, just not how to achieve it.
C is below:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int i;

  for ( i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) {
    int len = strlen(argv[i]);
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < len-1; j++)
      printf("%c*",argv[i][j]);

    printf("%c\n",argv[i][j]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There is an easier way in Python:

```
>>> '*'.join('james')
'j*a*m*e*s'
```

This makes use of the fact that in Python, strings are iterable.

Comment: Is there any way to do this using iteration?

Comment: @Elsavador: This above does use iteration (`join` iterates over the characters of `'james'`). Could you clarify what exactly you mean?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy:

```
name = 'james'
print '*'.join(name)
```

**Edit**:

To understand how its done here is a more verbose code that explains the concept.

```
name = 'james'

decorated_name = name[0]

for letter in name[1:]:
    decorated_name = decorated_name + '*' + letter

print decorated_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> "*".join(list("James"))
'J*a*m*e*s'
```

Always look if there's another way before reinventing the wheel :P.